# Godaddy - Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a form that inserts data into a mysql database located at Godaddy.  This sql code will work when I test locally.  But when I push it out to Godaddy, I get the error: "Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods".  I have googled and looked on SO for this error.  There wasn't much out there, but I did find a couple things talking about setting the CAS trust level on the server.  I did find that in the asp.net settings in my Godaddy account and set that to "full".  But it did not fix the error.
Here is the c#/mysql code that is throwing the error:

```
try
{
  using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(appConfig._strMYSqlContact))
  {
    // create the sql command
    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySQL, connection);
    // add parameters
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?groupname", model.grName);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?groupsize", model.grSize);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?contactname", model.coName);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?address", model.address);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?city", model.city);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?state", model.state);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?zipcode", model.zip);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?county", model.county);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", model.email);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?phone", model.phone);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?calltime", model.bestTime);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?message", model.message);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?howheard", model.howHeard);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?moreaboutclubs", model.tellUsMore);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?dateentered",
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    connection.Open();
    isSuccess = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  if (isSuccess == 1)
  {
    TempData["message"] = "Thank you for contacting us.  Someone will be in contact with you within 48 hours.";
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
  }
  else
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error inserting into database.");
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This is a candidate for a ticket in Godaddy rather than in SO

Comment: Already talked to Godaddy on the phone and they weren't able to figure it out.  Doesn't look like Godaddy has a ticket system anymore.

Comment: So that is why I came here looking to see if anyone could help.